# Mysql SELECT in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this :

```
+--------+---------------------------------------+
| CandId | Speak                                 |
+--------+---------------------------------------+
|      1 | English                               |
|      1 | Spanish                               |
|      2 | English                               |
|      2 | Spanish                               |
|      3 | Dutch                                 |
|      3 | English                               |
|      4 | Dutch                                 |
|      4 | Spanish                               |
|      4 | German                                |
+--------+---------------------------------------+
```

I'm trying to make a query that would for instance get the CandId of people that speaks English and Spanish (not or Spanish).

So in the specific case the query would show 1 and 2.

It's surely very easy but I even can't imagine how to do this.

Many thanks by advance for your help.

Comment: Although I consider your explanation easy to understand, it would have been better had you shown the expected result (which I assume is two rows containing the IDs 1 and 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column name `CandId` suggests that you have a `Cand` table containing the people. You can then select from that table and look up the languages with `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
select *
from cand
where candid in (select candid from cand_languages where speak = 'English')
  and candid in (select candid from cand_languages where speak = 'Spanish')
order by candid;
```

With a large table, you would provide an index to get the lookup fast:

```
create index idx on cand_languages(speak, candid);
```

Comment: Your solution worked, thanks ! Others surely work too but yours was simplier to adapt to my case.
Thanks to all others, your answers will help in the future, i'm sure.

Comment: This solution is probably inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CandId
  FROM Candidate
 WHERE Speak in ('English','Spanish')
 GROUP BY CandId
HAVING COUNT(CandId) = 2
```

It returns all CandId for which there are 2 records which match 'English' or 'Spanish'.
If you search for more languages also change in the HAVING clause the value of 2 in the number of languages.

UPDATED (thanks to spencer7593 for the valid comment):
if the combination CandId+Speak is not unique, one must use:

```
SELECT CandId
  FROM Candidate
 WHERE Speak in ('English','Spanish')
 GROUP BY CandId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Speak) = 2
```

Comment: We should not that this solution assumes that the (CandId,Speak) tuple is unique. Its true that there aren't any duplicates in the example data provided, but we should be careful to note that we are making an assumption of uniqueness, or we could craft the query to handle duplicates, e.g. we could tweak the HAVING clause `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Speak) = 2`

Comment: +10  the updated version will handle the more general case when the (CandID,Speak) tuple is not unique. Its a reasonable assumption that this would be unique. But its good to document that assumption if a solution depends on it. This is how I would do it.

Answer (score 2):

Aggregation with a having clause is a very general way to answer these "set-within-a-set" questions.  For both English and Spanish:

```
select candid
from t
group by candid
having sum(language = 'English') > 0 and
       sum(language = 'Spanish') > 0;
```

If you don't want Spanish:

```
having sum(language = 'English') > 0 and
       sum(language = 'Spanish') = 0;
```

Nuahatl and Amdo but not Mandarin:

```
having sum(language = 'Nuahatl') > 0 and
       sum(language = 'Amdo') > 0 and
       sum(language = 'Mandarin') = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the table on itself using the CandId:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT t1.CandId
FROM
    `table` t1
    JOIN `table` t2 ON t2.CandId = t1.CandId
WHERE
    t1.Speak = 'English'
    AND t2.Speak = 'Spanish';
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97635c/3 for a working example

Comment: `INDEX(CandId, Speak)` would be beneficial if the table is large.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE+SUM to count language for every candidate and then select only having count=2:

```
select CandId
from
(
select CandId, 
sum( case speak
      when 'English' then 1
      when 'Spanish' then 1
      else 0
    end)  countlang
from Table
group by CandId
)x
where countlang=2
```

Comment: Woaw many thanks for all these answers, I'll give a try asap

Comment: please try it )

Comment: Processor, do you run it?)

Comment: Hi, yes I used Thorsten Kettner method. I think it works but  I just but have another issue related to PHP, that's prevent me to be sure that is works. I'm on holiday so that's a little bit difficult to check it. I'll update asap.